# Return массива в С++

Tags: c++, массивы, return

Нужна функция, которая создавала бы массив из цифр четырехзначного числа. Однако при попытке вывести массив через return компилятор ругается: "Тип возвращаемого значения не соответствует типу функции".

```
int NumSeparator(int xn) {
    int xz[4]{};
    xz[0] = xn / 1000;
    xz[1] = xn / 100 % 10;
    xz[2] = xn / 10 % 10;
    xz[3] = xn % 10;
    return xz;
}
```

Если подставить указатель, то выдает ошибку: "возвращение адреса локальной или временной переменной: xz"

```
int *NumSeparator(int xn) {
    int xz[4]{};
    xz[0] = xn / 1000;
    xz[1] = xn / 100 % 10;
    xz[2] = xn / 10 % 10;
    xz[3] = xn % 10;
    return xz;

int main() {
int x = 1234;
x1 = *NumSeparator(x);
cout << x1;
```

[image: Вывод консоли после компиляции и выполнения кода]}

Comment: Простой способ вернуть массив (его копию) из функции, это заключить массив в структуру и возвращать уже ее

Comment: Возвращайте вектор, это проще всего.

Comment: Используйте вместо массива `std::array<int, 4>`. Его же и возвращайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы решить Вашу задачу Вам нужно сделать вот так:

```
    #include <iostream>

    int* NumSeparator(int, size_t);


    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        const size_t N = 4;
        int x = 1234;

        int* result = NumSeparator(x, N);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;
        }

        delete []result;

        return 0;
    }


    int* NumSeparator(int xn, size_t N)
    {
        int *xz = new int[N];
        xz[0] = xn / 1000;
        xz[1] = xn / 100 % 10;
        xz[2] = xn / 10 % 10;
        xz[3] = xn % 10;
        return xz;
    }
```

Но создавать массивы в функциях это плохая практика в языке С++. Это может привести к утечке памяти. Лучше создавать массив отдельно а потом передавать его адрес в функцию и уже в функции проводить над ним разные операции. Так не придется возвращать массив из функции. Соответственно минимизируется риск утечки памяти.

Comment: "Соответственно минимизируется риск утечки памяти" — в фукции, в которую вы передаёте массив, но не там, где он создался. Лучше использовать `std::vector` или `std::unique_ptr` для этих целей.

Answer (score 0):

Во втором случае при выходе из метода локальные переменные очищаются.

```
int *NumSeparator(int xn) {
    int *xz = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    xz[0] = xn / 1000;
    xz[1] = xn / 100 % 10;
    xz[2] = xn / 10 % 10;
    xz[3] = xn % 10;
    return xz;
}
```

Нужно выделить пямять для четырех значений, она может быть очищена только вызовом `free` или по завершении программы.

Comment: Хорошо, я попробовал использовать выделение памяти, но он выдает ошибку E0144: значение типа "void*" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "int*".

Comment: @dikobrxz, у вас какой-то строгий компилятор. Попробуйте привести к типу **int**.

Comment: @Olegator36 не строгий, а соответствующий стандарту. См. https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/6944845 и https://stackoverflow.com/q/15118990/6944845.